# I am calling a Rest API Curl command using python, But the post request is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, curl

So here is my curl command, In command line, curl script is working fine

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json" -u user:password URL -d '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'
```

Now I have converted my code to python and the code look like this :

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}'

requests.post('URL', headers=headers, data=data, auth=('user', 'password'))
```

When I ran this code, I am not getting any output.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, the 'url' parameter in `requests.post` should be an complete url including the 'http://' or 'https://'.
Secondly, if you need to post some data in form of `application/json`, using Python protogenic `dict` will be fine. like this
`data = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`

Comment: Issue was with the single quotes, Thank you for highlighting it.

Answer (score 0):

you might be looking at something like this?

```
r = requests.post("http://{}/Command?".format(web_addr), params=dict)
print r.text
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6.1, you should get the response 200 message if the following code gets executed, with a existing 'URL':

```
from requests import post
data = {"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
print(post('URL', json=data))
```